# Matching the elements in a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list in which there are 10 elements. I am showing the 8th, 9th and 10th element of my list.

```
 > a[8]
 [[1]]
 [1] BUFMARINE   COLDEPS      M1RED     ORGM1T3   JELLYBIN  
 [6] MULTITASK    PBA       UVRAYS     UVBRO        

 > a[9]
 [[1]]
 [1] PBA         MULTITASK      M1RED     ARITHRO   ORGM1T3  
 [6] BACKUP      BUFMARINE      FIRELANE  PRITH     SOLTS
 [11]REDMOS

 > a[10]
 [[1]]
 [1] PRITH       M1RED          BUFMARINE     ORGM1T3   OLAX     
 [6] PBA         FIRELANE       ANADS         ZEPRO     BLUEPACK
 [11]SOLTS       ARACUS         SOLVIN        SUES
```

As you can see, the number of elements within each element of the list differ. 
In a[8] and a[9] we can see that there are 5 matching strings i.e BUFMARINE,M1RED,ORGM1T3,MULTITASK and PBA. The total strings inside a[8] and a[9] are 9+11=20. Thus we can say that a[8] matches a[9] by (5*2*100)/20 =50%
This way I want to match all combinations and find which two set of list elements have greater percentage of strings matching. The order in which the strings are present inside each list is not important to me so when taking a combination of two list items (ex a[2] and a[4]) I want to match each string of a[2] with each string of a[4] to see if we have a match.

Comment: You may find caTools and intersect useful here.

Comment: I'm not sure whether "The total strings inside a[8] and a[9] are 9+11=20. Thus we can say that a[8] matches a[9] by (5*2*100)/20 =50%" is true - see answer from @lukeA. The second element contains 50% of  the third elements, and there are 100% matches of the 2nd element in the third - however, the result is 33.3% (which is correct following your formula, but I guess your formula and what you wrote is not the same, probably)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
set.seed(3)
( lst <- replicate(3, sample(letters[1:5], sample(1:5, 1), F)) )
# [[1]]
# [1] "e"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "b" "c"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "a" "b" "d" "c"
( combis <- combn(seq(lst), 2) )
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    2
# [2,]    2    3    3
apply(combis, 2, function(x) {
  length(intersect(lst[[x[1]]], lst[[x[2]]])) / ( length(lst[[x[1]]])+length(lst[[x[2]]]) )*100
})
# [1]  0.00000  0.00000 33.33333
```

?

Comment: This works. Thanks. I want to save this output to a variable so that I can write it to a file.

Comment: If you assign the output of `apply` to a variable, say `->res`, then you can use sth like `write.csv(cbind(t(combis), res))` to write is to a file.

Comment: I tried result<-apply(combis, 2, function(x) { .... but the result shows NULL. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Also is there a way we can compare two factors with differing number of levels?

Comment: Yes, but the result is the vector (last commented line)

Comment: Why not factors? Imho no difference.

Comment: Oh sorry! I have actually made some modifications to the code as I am working on a very big dataset. I used cat("\nMatching between", x[1], "and", x[2], "is", prct) inside apply. But as cat is itself a stdout function so should not be used here if I want to save my result to another variable. What could I use here to get a dataframe as a result which has 3 columns of x[1],x[2] and prct  ?

Comment: As I said: `cbind(t(combis), res)`